# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 (x_n-x_{n+p}) $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and $F$ a primitive of $f$ for which $F(0)=0$.

a) Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an unique $x_n$ such that $F(x_n)=\frac{1}{n}$.

This is easy...

b) Find $\lim_ { n \to \infty } nx_n$.

This is how I solved it: $F$ is increasing. We consider $G: \mathbb{R} \to F(\mathbb{R} )$ such that $G(x)=F(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly G is one-to-one so it is inversable. We get that $x_n=G^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ and $G^{-1}(0)=0$. So: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n x_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} n G^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)=\lim_{ x \searrow 0} \frac{G^{-1}(x)}{x}=(G^{-1})'(0)=1. $

Is this OK?

c)Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 (x_n-x_{n+p}) $, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

I wrote this limit as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{G^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)-G^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{n+p} \right)}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=p \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{G^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)-G^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{n+p} \right)}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+p}}. $

But here I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Cauchy Mean Theorem for $f(x)=G^{-1}(x), g(x)=x$ in $[\frac{1}{n+p},\frac1n]$ for (c). It seems to me part (b) is correct.